# Possibility to create a multiplatform desktop application on Visual Studio for Mac in C#, but build it on windows

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac, multiplatform, maui

as the title already mention my question is about the following:

I 'm looking for a possibility to create a multiplatform desktop project on Visual Studio for Mac. After creating that, I'd like to just kinda "import" that project in Visual Studio for Windows (of course on a windows vm) and just build it there to run it on Windows 10. I know that maybe only "importing" a project would not do the job. I thought I would be a proper way to do it with Xamarin Forms on Visual Studio for Mac, but I cannot find such a solution. Does anybody know any approach of multiplatform solution that fits my needs? I hope my problem is getting clear. Apologize if there is such a question already answered, but I did not find any information regarding this.

I'm running windows in a virtual machine, and it is just not comfortable to code on vm for my opinion. So maybe some of you guys may have an idea how to achieve that. Thank you in advance

Comment: VS Mac can't create a UWP project.  You can create the Mac desktop solution on the Mac, then use VS on Windows to add the UWP project to the existing solution.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is it really that easy? But I have to use Xamarin for that right?

Comment: @dennis605 uwp is based on window development, Xamarin extends the .NET developer platform with tools and libraries specifically for building apps for Android, iOS, tvOS, watchOS, macOS, and Windows. You can use it to create app for multiple platform.

Comment: @cherry bu-msft thanks for your reply. I‘m going to try that.

Comment: @dennis605 Yes, you can do it, if you have any idea, you can share it here.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't stipulate which virtual machine you were using so I'll assume you're talking about "vmware fusion" so:

To configure a shared folder in a Windows virtual machine:

1. Launch VMware Fusion.
2. Power on the virtual machine.
3. Click Virtual Machine > Settings.
4. Click Sharing.
5. In Fusion 10.x, 8.x and 7.x select Enable Shared Folders. In Fusion 6.x, 5.x and 4.x, turn ON the Shared folders option. In Fusion 3.x, select the Share folders on your Mac option.
6. Click the + button.
7. Browse to the folder on the Mac that will be shared with the virtual machine and click Add.

Shared folders can be accessed via the VMware Shared Folders shortcut on the Windows desktop or the mapped network drive Z:.

[If you can't follow along, follow this explanatory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iksh6SO9L5A)

Comment: thanks for you explanation, but my question is more about, how to make it work, that I can create one application on one platform (Mac) and build it on an other (Windows). Please ignore, that I'm using a vm for that. That doesn't matter for me. I'm going to adjust my title, maybe the "vm" thing is a bit confusing.Thanks anyway for your reply